# Is it possible to create ENUM class so that it's entries were taken from application.yml?

Tags: spring, kotlin

given that application.yml contains:

```
values: "WEB", "MOBILE"
```

Can I create such class:

```
enum class Channel {
    WEB,           
    MOBILE
}
```

and not to list `WEB`, `MOBILE` literally in the code, bu instead, take them from the properties?

Comment: No. Enums are static so that isn't possible. Unless you dynamically create a class with something like ByteBuddy or ASM for instance. Also how are you going to use an enum in your code without static values?

Comment: sure you can dynamically create enum class in runtime after reading `application.yml` properties but how do you plan to use it?